# Using email.message to parse an HTTP POST request?

Tags: python, parsing, http-post, wsgi, python-3.11

With the deprecation of the standard `cgi` library in favor of [WSGI](https://peps.python.org/pep-3333/) starting in Python 3.11, the documentation [alleges](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/cgi.html):

> The `FieldStorage` class can typically be replaced with … the [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/email.message.html#module-email.message) module or [3rd-party] [multipart](https://pypi.org/project/multipart/) for `POST` and `PUT`.

However, it's not at all obvious how the first of these (using the standard library to parse HTTP POST requests) is actually done.

For example, the following code hangs on `EmailBytesParser.parse()`:

```py
import wsgiref.simple_server
import email.parser

import logging

_EmailBytesParser = email.parser.BytesParser()

def main_wsgi(environ, start_response):
    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET':
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        yield '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><label for="username">username:</label><input name="username" value="user123" /><br /><label for="avatar">avatar: </label><input name="avatar" type="file"><br /><input type="submit" value="register" />'.encode()
    else:
        assert environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
        assert environ['CONTENT_TYPE'].startswith('multipart/form-data')
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        logging.debug("About to start parsing form data...")
        # body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']))
        body = _EmailBytesParser.parse(environ['wsgi.input'], headersonly=True)
        logging.debug("Form data parsed!")
        yield repr(body).encode()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8000, main_wsgi).serve_forever()
```

I wasn't able to find any code examples online actually demonstrating the `email` module's suitability for this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Arguably ([and I do](https://discuss.python.org/t/using-email-module-as-a-replacement-for-cgi/26430)), the `email` module is *barely* worth it for parsing POST request bodies. "What you're doing wrong" could be argued (though I haven't) to be "trying to parse a POST request in 2023 without 3rd-party libraries".

WSGI, which is being pushed as the essential replacement for CGI, doesn't provide everything the `email` library needs to parse the request body all in one place. You'll need to inject a header beforehand to prime it (a) that the message is `multipart`, and (b) what the `boundary` between the form fields is. Then you need to `Message.iter_parts()`, and from each of these `Message.get_payload()` for the value, `Message.get_filename()` for the names of any file attachment uploads, and the ["legacy" function](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message.get_param) `get_param('name', header='content-disposition')` for field names because the non-legacy replacement, `Message.get_name()`, doesn't seem to exist yet.

Here's a working draft I threw together this afternoon; I don't like it, but can't see any better approaches for now:

```py
import wsgiref.simple_server
import email.message, email.parser, email.policy
import urllib.parse
import re
from collections import namedtuple
try:
    from resource import getpagesize
except ImportError:
    import mmap
    def getpagesize():
        return mmap.PAGESIZE

FieldEntry = namedtuple('FieldEntry', ["name", "value", "filename", "MIMEtype"])
FieldEntry_T = 'tuple[str, Optional[bytes], Optional[str], Optional[str]]'

def wsgi_parseForm(environ, /):
    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET':
        for k, v in _parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING']):
            yield FieldEntry(k, v, None, None)
        return
    m = email.message.Message()
    m.add_header('Content-Type', environ['CONTENT_TYPE'])
    match m.get_content_type():
        case 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            for k, v in _parse_qs(bytes().join(_wsgi_body(environ)).decode('ascii')):
                yield FieldEntry(k, v, None, None)
            return
        case 'multipart/form-data':
            p = email.parser.BytesFeedParser(policy=email.policy.HTTP)
            p.feed(('Content-Type: %s\r\n' % environ['CONTENT_TYPE']).encode('utf-8'))
            # ^Don't try to abbreviate this line; it also injects the boundary parameter, which is needed to parse out the sub-messages!
            p.feed('\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            for chunk in _wsgi_body(environ):
                # TODO stream each element to the caller as they arrive
                # rather than loading them all into RAM at the same time
                p.feed(chunk)
            m = p.close(); del p
            assert m.is_multipart()
            for part in m.iter_parts():
                part.set_default_type(None)
                yield FieldEntry(
                    part.get_param('name', header='content-disposition'),
                    part.get_payload(decode=True),
                    part.get_filename(None),
                    part.get_content_type()
                )
        case t:
            raise ValueError('unexpected Content-Type: %s' % t)


def _wsgi_body(environ, /):
    # Workaround helper function for https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66077
    wsgi_input = environ['wsgi.input']
    try:
        _read = wsgi_input.read1
    except AttributeError:
        def _read(n=getpagesize(), /):
            return wsgi_input.read(n)

    if environ.get('wsgi.input_terminated', False):
        # https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/4.9.4/docs/configuration-directives/WSGIChunkedRequest.rst
        try:
            yield from iter(wsgi_input)
            return
        except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
            while chunk := _read():
                yield chunk
            return
        
    if 'HTTP_TRANSFER_ENCODING' in environ:
        # https://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2007-March/002630.html
        # https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/proposals-2.0.html#unknown-length-wsgi-input
        # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#chunked_encoding
        raise NotImplementedError("Transfer-Encoding: %s" % environ['HTTP_TRANSFER_ENCODING'])

    toread = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0) or 0)  # Weirdly, this is set to the empty string for requests with no body, hence the or-clause
    readsofar = 0
    while (readsofar < toread):
        chunk = _read()
        readsofar += len(chunk)
        yield chunk


_QSSPLIT = re.compile(r'(?:^|&)([^&]*)')
_QSPARAM = re.compile(r'^(.*?)(?:=(.*))?$', re.DOTALL)
def _parse_qs(qs: str) -> 'Iterable[tuple[str, Optional[bytes]]]':
    for p in (m.group(1) for m in _QSSPLIT.finditer(qs)):
        k, v = _QSPARAM.match(p).groups()
        k = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(k)
        v = urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(v.replace('+', ' ')) if v is not None else v
        yield k, v


def main_wsgi(environ, start_response):
    from pprint import pformat
    if (environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') and (not environ.get('QUERY_STRING')):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        yield '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">'.encode()
        yield '<label for="username">username:</label><input name="username" value="user123" /><br />'.encode()
        yield '<label for="password">password:</label><input name="password" value="lol456" /><br />'.encode()
        yield '<label for="avatar">avatar:</label><input name="avatar" type="file"><br /><input type="submit" value="register" />'.encode()
    else:
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        yield pformat(list(wsgi_parseForm(environ))).encode()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8000, main_wsgi).serve_forever()
```

Perhaps studying one of the existing library implementations could be educational or enlightening.

Comment: One of the core Python developers suggested looking into the `policy` parameter to see if it offers any opportunity for cleaning up the code.